# SQL UPDATE Select row based on column cross referenced values

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause, multiple-columns

I would like to do an update to a row based on a value in another column.

Example table

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
'A' | ''  | 100
'B' | ''  | 120
'C' | 'A' | 0

UPDATE Table SET Col3 = Col3 - 10 WHERE Col1 = 'A'
```

However, if Col2 is not blank then I want to update the row that has it's value in Col2 so that

```
UPDATE Table SET Col3 = Col3 - 10 WHERE Col1 = 'C'
```

would update the Col1 = 'A' row

update

I discovered the following query works for me

```
UPDATE Table SET col3 = Col3 - 10
WHERE Col2 = '' and Col1 = 'C'
OR Col1 = (SELECT Col2 FROM Table WHERE Col1 = 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

where tbl is the table name

```
update tbl set col3=col3-10
from tbl t
inner join tbl tt
 on t.col1=tt.col2 or t.col2=''
where t.col1 = 'C'
```